Conditional JSON Schemas depending on URL path parameter
I'm trying to write an OpenAPI document, involving a PUT request with a parameter in the path, something like PUT /settings/{settingId}
I want the JSON payload to be minimalistic, looking like this:
{
  "value": "something" 
}

The settings at hand, identified with their settingId, must respect various types, patterns or regular expressions, for which I'd like to use JSON schemas. For exemple, if settingId = eth_enable, I want value to be a boolean.
I'm a beginner in the field, but it feels like the answer to my problem is not on the internet yet, and that's why I'm asking here now (after asking ChatGPT, who led me on a wrong path for about a week ). Is what I am trying to do feasible with JSON schemas, or are path parameters unusable with JSON schemas?
Thanks in advance for any and all hints!
I have searched for an answer on the internet for a while now, but it seems that all the implementations I found were JSON schemas based on properties, never on path parameters.

describing a different payload is possible, but it's not so easy to communicate which payload will work and there is no way to define only one schema based on the path parameter value. You must define both schemas.
the only way to distinguish them is by using the title attribute in the schema.
openapi: 3.1.0
info:
  title: thing
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  '/xxxx/{some_value}':
    put:
      description: my endpoint
      parameters:
      - name: some_value
        in: path
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
      requestBody:
        $ref: '#/components/requestBodies/my_put_request'
      responses:
        '200':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/200'
components:
  responses:
    '200':
      description: thing
      content:
        'application/json':
          schema:
            properties:
              value: 
                type: string
          examples:
            eth_enabled:
              value: { value: something }
  schemas:
    schema-one:
      title: schema_one
      type: object
      properties:
        value:
          type: boolean
    schema-two:
      title: schema_two
      type: object
      properties:
        value:
          type: string
  requestBodies:
    my_put_request:
      description: thing
      content:
        'application/json':
          schema:
              anyOf:
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/schema-one'
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/schema-two'
          examples:
            eth_enabled:
              value: { value: true }
            eth_disabled:
              value: { value: something }
      required: true


Thanks for the quick reply Jeremy! (and for the question formatting, too)
Thanks for the thorough code canvas, but since a JSON with a value that fits the wrong path parameter (meaning, another path parameter value than the one in the request with said JSON as payload) will be deemed valid by one of the schemas, it won't work.
As you write "There is no way to define only one schema based on the path parameter value", I understand I cannot obtain the behaviour I was aiming for.
This means I can now focus on alternate architectural solutions, so thank you so much for the reply again!
