AWS CDK API GW Model JsonSchema
I'm using OAS3.0 to define the schema for the API GW Model construct schema property. Works well except for this use case.
I have a request payload, where one property's type depends on the value of another.
So in OAS3.0, we end up with a "oneOf" array with a discriminator defined who's value determines which type to use in the "oneOf" array.
I can't deploy this to CDK as i get an error on use of the discriminator property.
Resource handler returned message: "Invalid model specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid model schema specified. Unsupported keyword(s): ["discriminator"]]...
It would be great if this property was supported to match the OAS3.0 spec, it's pretty close, but without this option I'm not able to document which "oneOf" type to use.
Is there another way to define this functionality?
Example schema being generated and used (Note discriminator can have mappings defined to explicitly define the value to type mappings, see https://spec.openapis.org/oas/latest.html#schema-object )
{
  "swagger": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "version": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "payload": {
        "oneOf": [
          {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "propA": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "propB": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "propA",
              "propB"
            ],
            "additionalProperties": false
          },
          {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "propC": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "propD": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "propC",
              "propD"
            ],
            "additionalProperties": false
          }
        ],
        "discriminator": {
          "propertyName": "version"
        }
      }
    },
    "required": [
      "id",
      "version",
      "payload"
    ],
    "additionalProperties": false
  },
  "components": {}
}

When i pass the schema defined above (OAS3.0) to the CDK Model construct, i am expecting API GW model to except the "oneOf" discriminator so it can be documented for clients of the API.
Instead i get error as it's not a supported property/feature
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.JsonSchema.html
But i can get OAS3.0 compliant schema JSON generated from my created API GW. Needs to work both ways.

this is the same idea. in a nutshell, you can only use the title property from each oneOf if they don't support discriminator.  There's no other way to indicate which schema is the correct one based on a property value.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78839862/conditional-json-schemas-depending-on-url-path-parameter/78839913#78839913
